# c# DotNet.Highcharts switch statement

Tags: c#, .net, highcharts

New to C# and struggling with EF and trying to perform switch/case within a foreach loop. I want to change the data from the query which is a number  to a string.

The data(key) from the query is 1 2 3. Is there a way of doing this that will work?

```
if (selectQuestion.SelectedValue == "1")
                {
                    var data = db.tbl_complaints_data
                        .Where(d => d.organisation_id == o.organisation_id
                        && d.Service == site
                        && d.Date.Month == month
                        && d.Q1 != null)
                        .GroupBy(d => d.Q1)
                        .Select(d => new { q1 = d.Key, total = d.Count() });

                    var segment = new List<object[]>();

                    foreach (var d in data)
                    {
                        segment.Add(new Object[] 
                        { 
                            switch (d.q1.ToString())
                            {
                                case "1":
                                    d.q1.ToString() = "Your care";
                                    break;
                                case "2":
                                    d.q1.ToString() = "Another's care [friend or relative]";
                                    break;
                                case "3":
                                    d.q1.ToString() = "Other type of complaint";
                                    break;
                            }, 
                            d.total
                        });
                    }

                    Render_PieChart(segment);
```

This is the pie chart if there is any interest.

```
protected void Render_PieChart(List<object[]> pData)
    {
        DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart
            {
                DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Pie
            })
            .SetTitle(new Title
            {
                Text = selectQuestion.SelectedItem.Text
            })
            .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle
            {
                Text = selectMonth.SelectedItem.Text
            })
            .SetSeries(new[]
                {
                    new Series 
                    {
                        Data = new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Data(pData.ToArray())
                    }
                })
            .SetCredits(new Credits
            {
                Enabled = false
            });

        ltrChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
    }`
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you your code is wrong:

1. You can't switch inside the `new Object[]` init --> `Invalid expression term 'switch'`
2. You can't assign a variable to a `ToString()` --> `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`

Rewrite it as:

```
var segment = new List<object[]>();
foreach (var d in data)
{
    string q1String = "Unknown";
    switch (d.q1)
    {
        case 1:
            q1String = "Your care";
            break;
        case 2:
            q1String = "Another's care [friend or relative]";
            break;
        case 3:
            q1String = "Other type of complaint";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    segment.Add(new Object[] 
    { 
        q1String, 
        d.total
    });
}
```

Comment: No more error messages and the code executes! New problem though and I can't yet see a reason for it. The pie chart itself no longer shows. If I set q1String = "test" in the segment.add it works. I stepped through the code and it does execute the switch statement as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel, Any errors on the JavaScript console?  I'm not familiar with `DotNet.Highcharts` but I'd imagine at some point it generates JavaScript.  What does `new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Data(pData.ToArray())` resolve to in the JavaScript?

Comment: Didn't even think to try that, issue was the ' in Another's. Escape character was required, however it required \\ instead of \. Must be a DotNet.Highcharts thing! Thank you for your help!